# What's the difference between Swift's Dispatchqueue and Flutter's Future?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart

First of all please don't laugh at my question I am still a newbie.
Recently I have started learning iOS development and found about **Dispatchqueue** ([documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue)).
After reading the documentation, I had a question on my mind.

- Is it similar like **Flutter's Future**([documentation link](http://%20https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future-class.html))? Or are there any differences between them? If yes, then what are the differences?

I searched a lot but couldn't find a proper answer which would clear my confusion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Someone will be able to provide a more complete answer but at a high level... `DispatchQueue` is more like a thread so different queues can be used to do work concurrently. Whereas `Future` is a promise that it will contain some value at some point in the ... erm ... future. Like if you are downloading an image you could use `Future<Image>`. Incidentally, Swift.Combine also has a `Future`, it is a fairly common idea across different programming languages..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DispatchQueue is for parallelization your tasks. It works according to the first in first out principle, means the first tasks will be done first etc.
A Future sounds for me like a "delayed" task, means your task will be done in the future but not in the background like in a DispatchQueue.
Some good information for DispatchQueue are here [Appropriately-using-dispatchqueue-main](https://www.donnywals.com/appropriately-using-dispatchqueue-main/) :-)